# Do I need to use .ToString() to make a string equal to an index of a string array

Tags: c#

Ok so I have a string array like so:

```
string[] myStringArray = new string[2];

myStringArray[0] = "Foo";
myStringArray[1] = "Bar";
```

To declare a new string and make it equal to the first string in my array do I do this:

```
string foo = myStringArray[0];
```

Or this:

```
string foo = myStringArray[0].ToString();
```

Fundamental stuff I know but if you don't ask...

Thanks

Comment: Just to add, I've been using ToString() up until now, and it just occured to me that I probably don't need to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this:

```
string foo = myStringArray[0];
```

Calling `.ToString` on a string instance simply returns this same instance so you don't need it. Here's how this method is defined for the string class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. `myStringArray[0]` is already a string, so you don't have to specify `ToString()` yourself. You would have to do it if `myStringArray[0]` wouldn't have been a string.

`ToString()` is a very low-level call that is defined for the most basic of all things, `object`. So it exists on all C# objects and you can call it on anything, even on things that don't need it.
E.G. You can write `"string".ToString().ToString()` and the compiler won't mind, it will just come out as `"string"`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call ToString()

Btw, if you decompile the String class, you'll see that this is the ToString() implementation:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As other said, `ToString()` on a `string` returns the string itself, so it's totally useless to call `ToString()`.

Actually it's even **dangerous**, as it could throw a `NullReferenceException` if your string is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `ToString()`, items of a `String[]` already are strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
string foo = myStringArray[0];
```

The above will do the purpose, if you have LINQ then you can use

```
string foo = myStringArray.First();
```

If you are not sure whether string array will have values all time then you can use

```
string foo = myStringArray.FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.